# Linux commands are hanging on ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

We are having a **VPC setup** for our staging environment. In this we have attached an **elastic ip to one instance & rest of the instances are connected through this**.

Now today when we restarted our machines we are facing **trouble running commands like top, vi, ps etc**.

Also we have noticed that if we **connect to secondary machines via their public ip then everything is working fine**. However if we **connect via primary machine then the screen hangs after the command is issued**.

Having a hard time debugging the root cause. Any suggestions will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for inconvenience. The problem was with our office network. It started automatically after sometime.